# How to select growth rate by month with this query?

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have a table that i'm using to save the database size, everyday.

I have this query using row_number():

```
select databasename, data_size,LOG_Size, data,  
        row_number() over (partition by month(data) order by data asc) from [dbo].[tblGDLIC_Size]
    where databasename = 'gdl_ic'
```

and i have this:

[image]

Ok, It's listing every day, with sizes and a row_number.

What I'm trying to do is to, by MONTH, list the growth rate.

I made this query but it's not what I need:

```
select
    databasename, max(data_size)-min(data_size) as 'Crescimento_Mensal',
    row_number() over (partition by month(data) order by data asc) from [dbo].[tblGDLIC_Size]
    where databasename = 'gdl_ic' 
    group by DatabaseName,data
```

is is better to use DENSE_RANK?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the table size never decreases it's a simple aggregation:

```
select databasename, month(data), 
   max(data_size)-min(data_size) as 'Crescimento_Mensal'
from [dbo].[tblGDLIC_Size]
where databasename = 'gdl_ic' 
group by databasename, month(data)
```

Otherwise you need some Analytical Functions:

```
with cte as
 (
    select databasename, data_size as first_val, 
        -- this is used to return the first date of a month in the next step
        row_number() over (partition by month(data) order by data asc) as rn,
        -- this is the data_size of the latest date in a month
        last_value(data_size)
        over (partition by month(data) order by data asc
              rows_between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as last_val
    from [dbo].[tblGDLIC_Size]
    where databasename = 'gdl_ic' 
 )
select databasename, last_val-first_val as 'Crescimento_Mensal'
from cte
where rn = 1 -- only return the first date
```

Comment: Hey @dnoeth. Thank you. I made somethig like your first query, but it's not working, for some reason, the difference between when I use this query, and when I manually calc the max - min is 15GB. I don't know why. And about the second query, what is ` rows_between unbounded preceding and unbounded following`. Is this sql server?

Comment: @RafaelPiccinelli: If the 1st query doesn't work as expected, the table size might both increase and decrease within a month. The `rows between ...` is Standard SQL syntax (& supported by SQL Server), the default `rows unbounded preceding` will not return what you need.